# Separating data in an istringstream

Tags: c++, friend-function, istringstream

I have parsed a string into variables using `std::istringstream`.

Here's the code:

```
Reservation rec;
Reservation::Reservation(): resID(""), resName(""), email(""), people(""), day(""), hour("")
{
}

Reservation::Reservation(const std::string & m_res): stringfile(m_res)
{
    std::replace(stringfile.begin(), stringfile.end(), ',', ' ');

    std::istringstream strm(stringfile);
    strm >> rec.resID >> rec.resName >> rec.email >> rec.people >> rec.day >> rec.hour;
}
```

Now my desired output for the is supposed to look like below (just a snippet from a larger output):

```
Reservation RES-001:       John  <john@email.com>        Drinks on day 3 @ 5:00 for 2 people.
Reservation RES-002:      David  <david@email.com>       Breakfast on day 4 @ 6:00 for 1 people.
```

Basically, what is throwing things off is that my `friend` function that is printing the data is being called in as a loop. My `std::istringstream` data is one piece of info after the next, no looping is required.

Here is the output I'm getting:

```
Reservation RES-020:: Donna<donna@email.com>breakfast on DAY 4 @ HOUR:24 for 3people
Reservation RES-020:: 20Donna<0donna@email.com>lunch on DAY 4 @ HOUR:24 for 3people
```

Now, I **CANNOT** change the call to the friend function. Here it is:

```
for (auto i = 0u; i < cnt; ++i)
{
    std::cout << *ppReservations[i];
}
```

And, here is my code that is outputting the formatted information that is repeating the same line (*this is a snippet, the rest of the function follows the same parameters just with different hour comparisons*):

```
if (std::stoi(rec.hour) >= '6' || std::stoi(rec.hour) <= '9')
{
    os << "Reservation " << rec.resID + ": " << rec.resName
       << "<" << rec.email + ">" << "breakfast on DAY " << rec.day
       << " @ HOUR:" << rec.hour << " for " << rec.people << "people\n";
}
```

So, the question is how can I get the desired output? Is there any way to modify my `std::istringstream` variables so that they can correspond to the `for` loop that calls the `friend` function so the output isn't the same line repeating over and over?

Comment: C++ doesn't have anything in the box (be quite pleased if you can prove me wrong) that will automatically center text. I generally build an appropriately padded string write the string to the stream.

Comment: @user4581301 its not just centering the text its fixing the issue with the duplication of the values thats the problem. and jeez tell me about it lol

Comment: Not directly related to the question but is this intentional? `std::stoi(rec.hour) >= '6'` in `if` statement. You are converting the string `rec.hour` to `int` and then comparing it with a `char` i.e. `'6'`. If your intention was to compare the ASCII values then you could simply write `rec.hour[0] <= '6'`. If this is an integer comparison, it should be `std::stoi(rec.hour) >= 6`. And, you don't have to concatenate `rec.resID + ": "` as you're directly writing to `os`, it should be written directly to the stream instead of concatenation.

Comment: Is `rec` here a string alias (`Reservation rec;`)? If you've only one `rec` variable then it'll be overwritten and you'll have the same value. You need a container e.g. `std::vector` to store multiple values. And, please add some more information about how this statement `std::cout << *ppReservations[i];` is linked with the values you're printing.

Comment: how exactly would i create a vector container? im sorry im not the best c++ programmer